# JS цикл c PHP переменными

Tags: php, javascript, html

Здравствуйте. Заранее спасибо за помощь. 
Опишу ситуацию. Есть данный HTML:

```html
<tr id="dayWrap">
  <td><span class="day1"><?php echo $product['price_1']; ?></span></td>
  <td><span class="day2"><?php echo $product['price_2']; ?></span></td>
  <td><span class="day3"><?php echo $product['price_3']; ?></span></td>
  <td><span class="day4"><?php echo $product['price_4']; ?></span></td>
  <td><span class="day5"><?php echo $product['price_5']; ?></span></td>
</tr>

<span class="total_cat" style="float: right; display: inline-block"></span>
```

В каждую ячейку для каждой таблицы вставляется своя цена. В итоге в `total_cat` будет выводиться сумма(`dif` (количество натуральных чисел) * значение переменной `$price_n`).
Есть JS:

```js
 //захват столбцов с ценами(дни)
let num = dayWrap.getElementsByTagName('span');

//записываем цены в массив
var values = [];
for ( let i = 0; i < num.length; i++ ) {
    values.push( num[i].innerHTML );
}
if (dif >=2 && dif <= 3 ) {
  for (var i = 0; i < day2.length; i++) {
    day2[i].classList.add("red-circle");//добавление стилей
  }
  classRemove(day1);//удаление стилей для других элементов
  classRemove(day3);
  classRemove(day4);
  classRemove(day5);

  var priceForTotal = values[1] * dif;//ТУТ КОСЯК!!!

  for(let i = 0; i< total.length; i++){//Вывод суммы в нужном формате
    total[i].innerHTML = "Всего: <br> За "+ dif + " дня(дней) " +'<br>' + priceForTotal + ' €';
  }
}
```

В комментарии показано место ошибки и суть вопроса. Нужно, чтобы цены адекватно считались если они подходят к условию `if`, если вызывать, через `values[1]`, то добавляется одна цена для всех остальных таких таблиц.

Как сделать динамический подсчет для всех таблиц с учетом корректных цен каждой таблицы(надеюсь, понятно объяснил=)).

Спасибо!

Comment: попробуем разобраться, а зачем собирать массив `values`, если вы обращаетесь только к `values[1]`, я так понимаю тут не весь код, и выше идет цикл по таблицам, можно показать? возможно туплю

Comment: @ maxkrasnov это не вы тупите. а я. В этом и вопрос. Как обращаться к корректным ценам КАЖДОЙ таблицы. Думаю что этот массив вообще лишний

Comment: а о `dif` можно по подробнее? "количество натуральных чисел" чего? кого?)

Comment: если каждой таблицы, то основной цикл должен начинаться с перебора таблиц, то есть `document.querySelectorAll('table')`, внутри цикла уже вы заводите нужные переменные и от каждой таблицы просчитываете ваши условия

Comment: @maxkrasnov о dif не думайте, считайте это любым числом(это разница дней между двумя датами). "внутри цикла уже вы заводите нужные переменные и от каждой таблицы просчитываете ваши условия"- можно немного подробнее, а то голова уже кругом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После комментариев, я так понял, проблема в том, что вы проходите по всем `span` из всех таблиц, и вы не можете посчитать данные для нужной, поэтому (хоть всего кода не видно), нужно всю конструкцию начать с цикла перебора таблиц

```
var tables = document.querySelectorAll('table')
for (i = 0; i < tables.length; ++i) {
   let num = tables[i].getElementsByTagName('span');
   // дальше num будут только для конкретной таблицы, а не у всех общая
   // ваш код
}
```

Comment: Извините, не совсем понимаю код. Сначала мы объявляем все таблицы в одну переменную, потом через цикл вызываем все span этой переменной. Как конкретизировать этот запрос для первой, пятой, десятой и тд таблиц? Нужно будет каждой таблице вызывать подобное? Просто они будут постоянно пополняться. Если нужен более подробный код, то могу попробовать предоставить.

Comment: в начале берем все таблицы в массив `tables`, там у вас все таблицы, затем циклом перебираем каждую таблицу `tables[i]`, где `i` - номер таблицы, `num` - это все значения `span` конкретной таблицы. Это один код для всех таблиц, внутри цикла перебирается каждая таблица страницы

Comment: спасибо Вам. Утром попробую, сейчас совсем все плохо) Спасибо за отзывчивость!

Comment: не вышло. Пробовал вот так. https://jsfiddle.net/e181rjLe/

Comment: @ВладЮдкин а почему часть кода за циклом? расчеты должны быть тоже в цикле, так как для каждой таблицы `values` будут собираться по новому, а то нет смысла в цикле по таблицам )

Comment: попробовал все совместить и в условии и вне.Если Вам не сложно я бы мог прислать вам сриншоты или подробные комментарии, напишите в телеграмм 'собака'YVDev или почту yudkinvlad@gmail

Comment: @ВладЮдкин кстати, пытался написать вам, ящика такого не существует

Comment: может не добавили точка ком? Но это не важно, вы очень помогли. Дальнейшая проблема была с выводом, уже разобрался.

Comment: @ВладЮдкин вот я тормоз, копи паст и даже не заметил, что нету кома (

Comment: Ничего страшного) Вы все равно напишите, если не сложно, иногда просто бывают ситуации, когда очень нужна помощь, а спросить не у кого.